# Seleccion de una opcion de un select en php

Tags: php, select, options

estoy intentando que cuando seleccione una opción de un select me realice una función, el problema que no se recoger ese valor en php, ¿como tendría que hacerlo?.

```
form action="" method="post">
                   <label>Selecciona que tipo de pago quieres visualizar:</label>
                    <select name="tiposDePagos" id="tiposDePagos">
                        <option value="listaPagos">Lista de Pagos</option>
                        <option value="ListaDeDeudores">Lista de Deudores</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
```

---

He intentado ponerle esto para ver si me podía coger el valor pero no me lo coge:

```
if ($_POST["listapagos"]) {
              verPagos();

                }
```

Comment: Si todo lo vas a hacer en la misma pagina de PHP tienes que hacerlo con AJAX, si lo vas a enviar a otra pagina de PHP en el action coloca la dirección de la otra pagina y luego en esa otra pagina utiliza el POST.

Comment: Lo quiero hacer sobre la misma página, el problema que quiero que se muestre la función donde quiero que se muestre una información y si le doy al otro option otra tabla con otra tabla

Comment: Entonces debes utilizar AJAX, puedes hacer una función que se ejecute con un onchange que tome el valor del select y en base al valor seleccionado haga una u otra acción.